# Camel: Delete the file with Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, apache-camel

I can not understand the Apache Camel. I need to delete a file from Google Drive. Below is my code.

private static List scopes = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file");

```
public static void main(String[] args ) throws Exception 
{       
     CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();  

        GoogleDriveConfiguration configuration = new GoogleDriveConfiguration();
        configuration.setApplicationName("camel");
        configuration.setClientId("..");
        configuration.setClientSecret("..");
        configuration.setScopes(scopes);
        configuration.setAccessToken("..");
        configuration.setRefreshToken("..");

        GoogleDriveComponent googleDriveComponent = new GoogleDriveComponent();
        googleDriveComponent.setConfiguration(configuration);
        context.addComponent("google-drive", googleDriveComponent);

        context.addRoutes(  
             new RouteBuilder()  
             {  
                @Override  
                public void configure() throws Exception  
                {  
                    from("google-drive://drive-files/delete?fileId=..").log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${body}");   
                }  
             });  
          context.start();  
          Thread.sleep(10000);  
          context.stop();  
       }}
```

Advise please something. What am I doing wrong?

Stacktrace:

org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "file",
    "locationType" : "other",
    "message" : "File not found: ..",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "File not found: .."
}

Comment: camel is about Integration, or helping with the integrations of various systems between them. While you could use the camel google-doc component, if you just want to "delete a file in google doc", then you should probably use something else.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! My main task - to deal with Camel. I would like to finish this program.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use camel instead of "from", I would start a route on a 1 time timer and next step in route would a method call in my own class that will accept the filename and delete it from google drive and then log the response. I do agree with @Jeremie B that you should probably not use camel to just delete 1 file.